# iMacros: Can I Select Option by display text instead of value?

Tags: imacros

I am looking to automate selecting an item from a list where the generated `HTML` looks like:

```
<select name="uid_1"">
<option value="0">All</option>
<option value="1">Option A</option>
<option value="2">Option B</option>
<option value="3">Option C</option>
</select>
```

I can use the iMacros script line to select Option A, which has a value of 1:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:myForm ATTR=NAME:uid_1 CONTENT=%1
```

But I need to select by the display text "`Option A`" as this will be more stable than the options value.

**Is this possible with iMacros?**

Note that I am using the iMacros plug in for Firefox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better answer: Use a $ instead of a %.

`TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:myForm ATTR=NAME:uid_1 CONTENT=$Option<SP>A`

Note: The `<SP>` command indicates a space and is case sensitive.